# onChange select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form name="storelocator_cities_form" id="storelocator_cities_form">
    <select name="storelocator_city" id="storelocator_city" onchange="storeLocatorForm.fetchStoresByCountryAndPostCode(this)">
         <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Hi i want to capture the option value and then compare it to a specific city and i'm stuck. I'am new with both JS and jQuery but i guess that i will need to do something like

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('#storelocator_city').on('change',function(){
        var city = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

I would like a way to see that i get the correct value in the var in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like a way to see that i get the correct value in the var in
>   the console

Sure  , but first :

Why do you have 2 onchange events ?

[image]

Anyway - to see the value in console : try this :

```
jQuery(function(){
     $('#storelocator_city').on('change',function(){
       var city = $(this).val();
       console.log(city); <------- Try this
    });
});
```